# wx.Panel with a menubar

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm wondering if someone could show me how to add a menubar to the code provided. My problem is I cant find any docs or anything on adding a menubar to wx.panel. Is this even possible? if you could show me how that would be great. here's my code:

```
class Panel1(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent, id):
# create the panel
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
    try:
        imageFile = 'resize.jpg'
        data = open(imageFile, "rb").read()

        stream = cStringIO.StringIO(data)

        bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage( wx.ImageFromStream( stream ))
        weather1 = "The current temp in Urbandale is %r" % (ob['tempF'])
        weather2 = "With the heat index the temp in Urbandale is %r" % (ob['heatindexF'])
        wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bmp, (0, 0))
        if ob['tempF'] >= '80':
            label2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, weather1 , wx.Point(20, 196))
        if ob['tempF'] <= '90':
            label2 =  wx.StaticText(self, -1, weather2 , wx.Point(20, 196))
        label2.SetBackgroundColour("white")
        jpg1 = wx.Image(imageFile, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()

        wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, jpg1, (10 + jpg1.GetWidth(), 5), (jpg1.GetWidth(), jpg1.GetHeight()))
    except IOError:
        print "Image file %s not found" % imageFile
        raise SystemExit

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame1 = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Weather", size = (316, 435))
Panel1(frame1,-1)
frame1.Show(1)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Menubars are added to Frames not Panels, The wxpython demo has examples of using menubars.

Comment: yes i know that but i coundn't figure out how to a a menubar to a pannel im new to wxpython

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial, it shows adding a menubar http://www.python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=516

Comment: yes but you dont understand where im coming from i cant add a menubar unless im using wxframe and im using wxpannel i dont get how to use both

Comment: You are using a Frame its there down the bottom of your code, you asigned it to frame1 and then you added your panel to it.

Comment: yes but theres no class that has wx.frame in it and i cant add it under class pannel1 and i dont have wxframe class were would i add it?